# How can I import google-api-python-client into Google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-import

I am new to Google app engine and I am trying to import google-api-python-client into project.

I made a lib directory in the project directory and did:
pip install -t lib/ google-api-python-client

Which seems to have worked but when I run gcloud app deploy I get the following error:

File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 6, in 
    import google.oauth2.credentials

I am not sure where to go from here.  I am not sure if I need to add something to the requirements.txt file or if I have done something else wrong.  Any pointers to the right direction will be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

```
I setup the following files:
## appengine_config

from google.appengine.ext import vendor

# Add any libraries install in the "lib" folder.
vendor.add('lib')

###

### Main.py

# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import flask

import google.oauth2.credentials
import google_auth_oauthlib.flow
import googleapiclient.discovery


File "/home/vmagent/app/main.py", line 6, in <module>
    import google.oauth2.credentials
```

Comment: I assume App Engine standard. Are you following these instructions? https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-libraries-python-27#vendoring

Comment: looks no problem for me ,you can check the python path, for your application to make sure.